# trying to draw shapes in javascript but function wont load in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying g to draw a shape with the js canvas tag I am keeping it in a function. When I load up the browser, it is just empty I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Here is the code.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  draw()
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  function draw()
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);



  ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
  ctx.fillRect(250, 250, 50, 50)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared your function in a wrong way, that's why it isn't working. You forgot to add curly brackets in function declaration. Also call a function after its declaration.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  function draw() { // added curly brackets
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);



    ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
    ctx.fillRect(250, 250, 50, 50)
  } // added curly brackets

  draw(); // after function declaration
}
```